# "Incompatible operand types int and string"

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

I just started learning code (Java specifically), and i'm testing out a password system where when you type the password it becomes the variable "password" and it checks to see if it equals password2, the actual password. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LogicalOperators {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        int password;
        String password2;
        password2 = "Call of Duty";

        System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
        age = test.nextInt();



            if (age >=18) { 
                System.out.println("You are old enough."); 
                System.out.println("Please enter the password:");
                password = test.nextInt();
                if (password == password2) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome back!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("The password you typed was incorrect.");
                }

            }else{
                System.out.println("You are too young."); 
            }   



    }   
}
```

I'm trying to check in the nested if statement whether the password I typed in matched password2, "Call of Duty"; but the problem is that it doesn't work with strings. The title of this question is the error that comes up. Can someone please help me?

Comment: This queston is not closed (that term has a very specific meaning on SO). If your question has been answered, simply accept the answer that helped you most.

Comment: To check whether two String are same you must use the `.equals ` method and not `==` which checks for reference. Also change password type to String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when comparing strings you should use equals instead of ==
So use

```
if(password.equals(password2){
do something
}
```

Comment: thank you, i tried it and it worked, but do spaces or caps not work because password2 equaled "Call of Duty" and i typed that in it didn't work, that i changed it to "hi" and it worked.

Comment: Check my comment below. If you use the `nextLine()` method, you can get the entire string entered by the user along with the spaces.

Answer (score 10):

I try to give a hint instead of providing the full answer:

Check the data types of `password` and `password2`. Why are they different?

Comment: password is what you input, and the code checks to see if it matches password2, which is what the actual password is.

Comment: int password; String password2; if (password == password2) is always false, an "int" can not be equal to a "String" ... (and in fact it wont even compile ... why don't you fix the compiler errors first ;D )

Comment: @Daniel: and why is `password` of type `int`? Can the user only input numbers?

Comment: i was trying to get it to work with int before i made it a string, but i didn't realize you can't use int and string in an if statement like that :3

Comment: @Daniel: what sense does it make as an `int`? Then the user could only ever enter numbers as the password and that can't ever be equals to "Call of Duty".

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a couple of changes.

First `password` should be of type `String` since you want to store a string here and compare it with another string.

Next, just after `age = test.nextInt();`, you should do a `test.nextLine()` to consume the newline at the end of the input. We don't want to read this when we read the password.

Next, you should use `password = test.nextLine();` to read the password entered by the user.

Lastly, you should compare it using: `if (password.equals(password2))`. `==` compares whether both the String objects have the same references, i.e., whether they are the same String objects as known to Java. You want `.equals()` here because it would compare whether the content of the two String objects are equal. In this case, `password` and `password2` refer to two different String objects which may have the same content.

Comment: The test.nextLine() doesn't seem to do anything, and changing test.next() to test.nextLine() for the password makes it so when you  input a correct age it shows "Please enter the password: The password you entered was incorrect."

Comment: Quoting the part from my response that is important to fix the issue you are having: "Next, just after `age = test.nextInt();`, you should put a `test.nextLine()` to consume the newline at the end of the input. We don't want to read this when we read the password."